# UINavigationController crashes when targeting iOS7 SDK

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5

I have a `UINavigationController`, that I use to transition between an 'Inbox' and 'Outbox' view controller.
It works fine in `iOS6`, but when I target `iOS7`, I get the following:

```
-[_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView setAlpha:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc383c90
```

This happens when I call

```
[rootNav pushViewController:outbox animated:NO];
```

I've enabled Zombies and used the Allocate instrument to get some more information.
I've attached a screenshot of what I found.
Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do with this information. Does anyone have any ideas?

Also, this app does not use a back button. Maybe this is the issue?

Thanks!

[image: Information on crash]

Comment: What do you mean you're not using back button? do you remove it manually?

Comment: We set the back button to hidden, and add a custom subview to UINavigationBar with a target, that then calls the push/pop

Comment: Please add related code.

Comment: I've been unable to resolve this issue at this point.It seems in addition to hiding the back button the code is also removing certain default views. I suspect that the issue may lie there, but the code is somewhat convoluted. Will post-back when I solve the problem.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this problem ? I have exactly the same exception for the same reasons.. :/

Comment: Unfortunately not. We're still struggling to find a solution. :(